# knockout.js data-bind each array of object

Tags: knockout.js

I have json returning:

```
{
  "school":
     {
       "students":[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},"firstName":"Jane", "lastName":"Doe"}]
     }
}
```

Then in my markup I have

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: school.students">
  <li><span data-bind="text: firstName"></span><span data-bind="text: lastName"></span></li>
</ul>
```

`school.students` must not be right since it isn't working. Can someone help me with the syntax?

Comment: not sure how to update the question since my li was lost... but basically I have data-bind"foreach: school.students"

Comment: Are you using the mapping plugin? We need to see the full context here of how you're creating your view model and any bindings of parent HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Knockout doesn't work quite like that. You need to build your JSON into some objects before you can use the `foreach` binding on it.

For example, create a student object with the properties that you need:

```
function Student(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);
}
```

Then when you have your JSON string (maybe in the success callback of your AJAX load) you can create a collection of these student objects from the data:

```
school.students = ko.utils.arrayMap(json, function(item) {
    return new Student(item.firstName, item.lastName);
});
```

You can then use the `foreach` binding as you have done in your small example. Of course I am assuming that you have created a viewmodel and correctly used `ko.applyBindings()`.

Answer (score 0):

they have a knockout mapping plugin for this.  run snippet below.

```js
var data = {
  "school": {
    "students": [{
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    }, {
      "firstName": "Jane",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    }]
  }
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: school.students">
  <li><span data-bind="text: firstName"></span><span data-bind="text: lastName"></span></li>
</ul>
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html